# Typing Break in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: desktop, xubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 12.04, and loathe the new interface so much I've switched to Xubuntu with sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop.

Very happy with that so far. But the typing break I always used to have set is part of gnome.

Is there an equivalent typing break app in xubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an equivalent which is called [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/). See the description from their site:

> Workrave is a program that assists in the recovery and prevention of
>   Repetitive Strain Injury (RSI). The program frequently alerts you to
>   take micro-pauses, rest breaks and restricts you to your daily limit.
>   Please refer to the feature comparison for a complete list of
>   features, and how the program performs with respect to other programs
>   on the market. The program runs on GNU/Linux and Microsoft Windows.